# i need to append the odd row data into even and delete the row

Tags: excel, append, vba

I need to append data of the alternate row like D1+D2 into excel, please tell mw how can i do that

I have big excel and i am looking for a VBA so that i can append the odd row data into even row and devel the odd row.

```
        Surgical        Surgical
10  $1,800  Unit    8/5/2011    unit
        Surgical        Surgical
10  $4,000  Unit    9/2/2011    unit
        Surgical        Surgical
10  $2,000  Unit    8/12/2011   unit
        Surgical        Surgical
10  $1,250  Unit    8/12/2011   unit
        Surgical        Surgical
10  $1,517  Unit    8/19/2011   unit
        Surgical        Surgical
10  $1,250  Unit    8/19/2011   unit
        Surgical        Surgical
10  $2,000  Unit    8/12/2011   unit
        Surgical        Surgical
10  $2,200  Unit    8/19/2011   unit
        Surgical        Surgical
10  $0  Unit    8/19/2011   unit
        Surgical        Surgical
10  $1,251  Unit    8/12/2011   unit
        Surgical        Surgical
10  $1,500  Unit    8/12/2011   unit
        Surgical        Surgical
10  $1,001  Unit    9/1/2011    unit
```

these are in two cell and i wand to add the data into upper one 
please help me with that

thanks in advance

Comment: I saw your previous question had two answers. In this sample what are you wanting combined? Or is this a sample of what you want? It is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this merely using the excel functions like this (assuming your original data is in the A column):

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,A1&" "&A2,"")
```

That should be copied on any column adjacent to the original data. Then perform a filter on the column containing this formula (command+shift+F on a macintosh, different on a windows machine) and set it to show only the blank rows and delete them.

If you want to do it in VBA

**Assuming the data is in the range A1:A10**:

```
Sub mergeAndDelete()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1:A10")  'set the range the data resides in

    For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count  'merge step
        If i Mod 2 = 1 Then   'this checkes to see if i is odd
            r.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = r.Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & r.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i


    For i = r.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        ' Check if i is even and delete the row in the next line
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then    
            r.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete  
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Also, this adds the even row to the odd row (based on the example you provided - which is different than what you actually said you needed.) Modify the `if` statements if needed.